# Grammar of 'why would I do that' ? Is it grammatical?

Tags: grammar

I've often heard people saying this. And even I say it when someone accuses me of doing something that I didn't do.

I'd say:

> Why would I do that?

But what's the grammar behind it?

Is it future from the past tense or something or what?